# remove segments of lines in R

Tags: r, line

I have these 3 lines:

```
line1 <- matrix(c(-1.81209, -1.80470, -1.80616, 55.68024, 55.67947,
                    55.67544), ncol=2)
line2 <- matrix(c(-1.80468, -1.80330, -1.79690, 55.68322, 55.68017,
                  55.67800), ncol=2)
line3 <- matrix(c(-1.79798, -1.80069, -1.78929, 55.68364, 55.68138,
                  55.67966), ncol=2)

line1L <- Line(line1)
line2L <- Line(line2)
line3L <- Line(line3)
my.lines <- Lines(list(line1L, line2L, line3L), ID="my.lines")
myLines <- SpatialLines(list(my.lines))

proj4string(myLines) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
myLinesSpatial <- spTransform(myLines, CRS("+init=epsg:27700 +datum=WGS84"))

plot(myLinesSpatial)
```

[image]

I need to discard any part of any line, that falls within 100m of any other
line. This will result in segments of each of the three lines being removed.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the [`rgeos`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) package, e.g. with `gBuffer` and `gDifference`:

```
library("rgeos")
library("rgdal")

line1 <- matrix(c(-1.81209, -1.80470, -1.80616, 55.68024, 55.67947,
                    55.67544), ncol=2)
line2 <- matrix(c(-1.80468, -1.80330, -1.79690, 55.68322, 55.68017,
                  55.67800), ncol=2)
line3 <- matrix(c(-1.79798, -1.80069, -1.78929, 55.68364, 55.68138,
                  55.67966), ncol=2)

lines <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(line1)), ID="1"),
                           Lines(list(Line(line2)), ID="2"),
                           Lines(list(Line(line3)), ID="3")))
l <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(lines, data=data.frame(ID=paste(1:3)))
proj4string(l) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
lt <- spTransform(l, CRS("+init=epsg:27700 +datum=WGS84"))

plot(lt, lty=3)
buf_list <- vector(3, mode="list")
res <- vector(3, mode="list")
for (i in 1:3) {
  ind <- setdiff(1:3, i)
  buf_list[[i]] <- gBuffer(lt[ind,], width=200)
  res[[i]] <- gDifference(lt[i, ], buf_list[[i]])
}
lapply(buf_list, plot, col="#FFFFFF90", add=TRUE)
lapply(res, plot, col="red", lwd=2, add=TRUE)
```

[image: R plot]

Answer (score -1):

iN ARCGIS buffer each line for the dataset and run each separately, take the separate shp outputs and combine into a single shp.

Comment: Unfortunately don't have acces to ARC, only R

Comment: The ideas in this reply are contained in "run ... separately" and "combine," but those instructions are too vague to be useful.

Comment: Whoever gave the downvote to @Lewis: if this is because title says 'in R', I added this in after, so please remove downvote

Comment: luciano, Although I did not apply the downvote, it seems possible it was made by someone wishing to provide some incentive for improving this (vague, ambiguous) answer and not just because it refers to ArcGIS.  (Downvotes can be reversed after a post is edited: they are not permanent.)